# Required field validation not firing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am building a MVC5 form and need to put validation for required fields. I am having several text controls that require to be validated. I tried putting the `[Required]` attribute on the model as well as added the `required` keyword in the `htmlattributes` on the client side but the validation never fires. Could somebody tell me how to handle this validation

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
     <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { Value = Model.CustomerNumber == 0 ? "" : Model.CustomerNumber.ToString(), @class = "form-control", style = "width:100%", @readonly = "readonly", required = "required" } })
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You just need a `[Required]` attribute on the property. Have you included the necessary scripts for client side validation?

Comment: And never set the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods. Set the value of `CustomerNumber` in the controller before you pass the model to the view

Comment: I have added the required attribute on the CustomerNumber field in the viewmodel. Havent added any client side script. Thought the annotation itseld should work

Comment: You need `jquery-{version}.js`, `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` in your view or layout

Comment: I do have reference to these files

Comment: They will be in your `Scripts` folder by default, and you should be using bundles to include them.

Comment: The text box control shows zero by default. I cant make the viewmodel nullable as that is a mandatory field. Hence was setting it blank if zero shows up. How do I handle that in the controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142052/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-tom).

Answer (score 0):

1. add `[Required]` or other validator Attribute to your Model fields.
2. add jQuery Validate libs to your `_Layout.cshtml` file.

Example :

```
...
<body>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
       @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
</body>
</html>
```